# How to get URL segment in react.js

Tags: reactjs, url

I have URL like `http://localhost:3000/register`. How can I get `register` segment inside `return()` in `React.js`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something along the lines would also work, **in case you don't always want to have the last segment**.

If you have the URL as string and want to parse it.
*Note: This won't work on IE11, but there are polyfills like: [GitHub for URL polyfill](https://github.com/lifaon74/url-polyfill#readme)* (for more information please read up on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL))

```js
const url = new URL("http://localhost:3000/register");
const pathname = url.pathname; // contains "/register"
```

in case you are trying to access the URL using the window object, you get the pathname almost for free:

```js
const pathname = window.location.pathname; // also contains: "/register"
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like below:

```
const  url = "http://localhost:3000/register";
const segment = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

This will give always last segment. Let's say if your URL is `http://localhost:3000/user/John.`

It would give segment as John

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
const fullUrl = "http://localhost:3000/register"; //use this to get the complete url => window.location.href;
const lastPart = fullUrl.split("/").pop(); //this will give you register.
```

Comment: This is invalid Javascript

Comment: @catgirlkelly Can you explain why it's invalid? Console.log lastPart prints the last part of the URL to the console.

Comment: You forgot the quotes around the URL :x